# Swift IOs not working converting from Dictionary to array

Tags: ios, swift

i converted the dictionary "type" to array of strings and it is working good

when i tried to dictionary "cost" the same way it giving bad execution error

```
    import Foundation

/* Path for JSON files bundled with the Playground */
var pathForHearthstoneJSON = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hearthstone_basic_set", ofType: "json")

/* Raw JSON data (...simliar to the format you might receive from the network) */
var rawHearthstoneJSON = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForHearthstoneJSON!)

/* Error object */
var parsingHearthstoneError: NSError? = nil

/* Parse the data into usable form */
var parsedHearthstoneJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(rawHearthstoneJSON!, options: .AllowFragments, error: &parsingHearthstoneError) as! NSDictionary

/* Start playing with JSON here... */
var origin = parsedHearthstoneJSON["Basic"]
var type = origin?.valueForKeyPath("type") as! [String]
var cost = origin?.valueForKeyPath("cost") as! [Int]

var counter = 0;

type[0]
cost[0]
```

Comment: Check the type 'origin?.valueForKeyPath("cost")' before assigning it to optional

Comment: can you show what "`cost`" looks like in the unparsed JSON stream?

Comment: the unparsed cost [<null>, 2, 0, <null>, <null>, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 5, 0, 0, <null>, 4, <null>, 1, <null>, 2, <null>, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3, <null>, <null>, <null>, 4, <null>, 1, <null>, 2, <null>, <null>, <null>, 4, 7, 1, <null>, 2, 3, 5, <null>, 1, <null>, 2, 4, 3, 6, 1, <null>, 0, 1, <null>, 3, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7, <null>, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, <null>, 2, 5, <null>, <null>, 4, 1, 1, …, <null>, 0, 1, 4, 5, <null>, <null>, 6, 1, 1, 7, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1]

Comment: So log the type of the "cost" key: `let cost = origin?.valueForKeyPath("cost") as! NSObject;`  `println(cost.class)`

Comment: the type of Cost is
"Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>"

Comment: You need to cast to `[Int?]` since you obviously have nils inside the array... -_-

Answer (score 0):

it worked like that

```
    /* Path for JSON files bundled with the Playground */
var pathForHearthstoneJSON = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hearthstone_basic_set", ofType: "json")

/* Raw JSON data (...simliar to the format you might receive from the network) */
var rawHearthstoneJSON = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForHearthstoneJSON!)

/* Error object */
var parsingHearthstoneError: NSError? = nil

/* Parse the data into usable form */
var parsedHearthstoneJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(rawHearthstoneJSON!, options: .AllowFragments, error: &parsingHearthstoneError) as! NSDictionary

/* Start playing with JSON here... */
var origin = parsedHearthstoneJSON["Basic"]
var type = origin?.valueForKeyPath("type") as! [String]
//var cost = origin!.valueForKeyPath("cost")
let cost = origin?.valueForKeyPath("cost") as! [NSObject];
//println(cost.class)
cost.dynamicType
var counter = 0;

type[0]
cost[3]
```

Comment: The reason this works is that your JSON has 'NULLS' in it, which get turned into [NSNull null] objects. So while "var cost = origin?.valueForKeyPath("cost") as! [Int]" doesn't work, this might (didn't try it though): "var cost = origin?.valueForKeyPath("cost") as! [Int?]". Now you have an array of optionals, and could iterate over that, creating a new array of just "Ints" while converting the null values to "0" or whatever.